# Almost Sure Convergence in $L^{p}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, on the same probability space, with law given by $\displaystyle \mathbb P(X_1=(-1)^{m}m)=\frac{1}{(cm^2\log m)}$ for $m\geq 2$ where $c$ is the normalization constant $\displaystyle c=\sum_{m\geq 2}\frac{1}{m^2\log m}$. Prove that $\mathbb E(|X_1|)=\infty$, but there exists a constant $\mu \not\in \{\pm\infty\}$ such that $\displaystyle (n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k})_{n\geq 1}$ converges to $\mu$ in probability. Does it converge almost surely, and in $L^{p}$?

---

Integral test to show $$\mathbb E(|X_1|)=\infty$$

$$\mathbb E(|X_1|)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}|\left((-1)^mm\right)\left(\frac{1}{cm^2\log(m)}\right)|\propto\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m\log(m)}$$

Which is on the order of $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x\log(x)}dx=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u}=\infty$, $u=\log(x)$

Hence the expectation diverges.

We have the result:

Let $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$, where $X_i$ are iid. Then $\frac{S_n}{n}-\mu_n$ converges in probability to 0 for some $\mu_n$ if and only if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} x\mathbb P(|X_1|>x)\rightarrow 0$

Then:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} x\mathbb P(|X_1|)>x\rightarrow 0=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left[k\left(\sum_{m=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^2\log(m)}\right)\right]$$

$$\sim k\int_{x=k}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2\log(x)}dx$$

$$=k\int_{\log(k)}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u e^{u}}du,\hspace{5mm} u=\log(x)$$

$$\leq k\frac{1}{\log(k)}\int_{\log(k)}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{u}}du$$

$$=\frac{k}{log(k)}\times e^{-\log(k)}=\frac{k}{\log(k)}\frac{1}{k}$$

Where the $\frac{1}{k}$ cancels with the $k$,

And then $\displaystyle \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\log(k)}\rightarrow 0$.

We do not have $L^{p}$ convergence because $\mathbb E(A_n)=\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proving the expectation diverges is a simple integral test. To show convergence in probability, prove the following result:

> Let $S_n=X_1+\ldots+X_n$, where $X_i$ are iid. Then $\frac{S_n}{n}-\mu_n$ converges in probability to 0 for some $\mu_n$ if and only if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} xP(|X_1|>x)\rightarrow 0$

To investigate almost sure convergence, play around with Borel Cantelli Lemma looking at $|S_n/n-\mu_n|>\epsilon$ infinitely often. In particular, take a look at $X_n/n>\epsilon$ infinitely often.

As far as $L_p$ convergence goes, generally $L_p$ convergence implies convergence in probability from something like Chebyshev's inequality, *which you don't have* since there is no first (and therefore no second) moment. Yet, you do have convergence in probability. What are the ways that $L_p$ convergence can fail in this case, if any?

Comment: Can you explain the integral test a little? What integral do I use to show the divergence of expectation?

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence

Comment: Questions: How do I prove the statement in the highlighted box? Also how do we prove the Borel Cantelli Lemma for the statements? In the case of $\frac{X_n}{n}>\epsilon$, Borel Cantelli's convergence requirements don't seem to be met.

Comment: You can find a proof of the highlighted statement on Durret's book: Probability - Theory and Examples. It is not hard.